# C# Item in checkedListBox gets selected even though box is unchecked

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

If I have an item that I check and then I decide to uncheck, the code somewhat believes it is still checked. The result is that when I click "Go" the table also lists the unchecked item. In this case, Brandon was first checked, then unchecked. Even though the name is no longer "checked", the table still brings it up.

[image: Item still checked]

This is what I have:

```
    string filterstring = "";
    private void checkedListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
            filterstring = "Responsible = '" + checkedListBox.Items[e.Index].ToString() + "' OR";
        else


        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
            filterstring = "";


        foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox.CheckedItems)
            {
                filterstring += " Responsible = '" + itemChecked.ToString() + "' OR";
            }
        filterstring = filterstring.Substring(0, filterstring.LastIndexOf("OR"));
    }
```

I suspect that the key is in this part of the code. Without it, it throws an exception:

```
private void checkedListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    { 
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
            filterstring = "";
    }
```

Any helps is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of checked items isn't updated until *after* the ItemCheck event is fired, so your for-each loop is not reporting accurate checked items.

To avoid that, use a BeginInvoke call:

```
  this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
    foreach (var itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems) {
      filterString += itemChecked.ToString();
    }
  }));
```

This code will basically run immediately after the ItemCheck event method is called.

Update:

Since you are getting an exception on the SubString code, try creating your filter text like this:

```
List<string> filters = new List<string>();

void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
  this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
    filters = new List<string>();
    foreach (var itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems) {
      filters.Add("'" + itemChecked.ToString() + "'");
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Responible = " + string.Join(" OR ", filters.ToArray()));
  }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lars. Unfortunately it keeps throwing me an exception: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Length cannot be less than zero."

Comment: @P.C If that's happening in your LastIndexOf line, well, that's a different problem.  Your LastIndexOf is returning -1, which you are using for a length of text, hence, kaboom.

Comment: Nevermind... my bad, I misplaced the code. Your answer was right from the beginning.

Comment: @P.C I updated the post with probably a cleaner way to create your filter text.